# Multiple request between Android client and Java server

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, server

I'm developing a client/server application where an Android client sends a request to a Java server and then show to the user a notification with the server's respose.
The requests are based on the LocationManager updates so they are very frequent.
I saw that the RTT is very high (about 6 seconds) and i want to make lower.
The time of the elaboration of request is trascurable.

Now i'm using the TCP protocol

This is the client

```
public abstract class Client extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{

private static final String DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS = "x.x.x.x";
private static final int PORT = 12345;

private String indirizzo;
private int porta;

public Client(String indirizzo, int porta){
    this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
    this.porta = porta;
}

public Client(){
    indirizzo = DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS;
    porta = PORT;
}

public abstract void receiveData(Object object);

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object...parametri)
{
    Object esito = null;

    try
    {
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(indirizzo);

        Socket socketClient = new Socket(inetAddress,porta);

        //OTTIENE GLI STREAM DI INPUT E OUTPUT
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socketClient.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socketClient.getOutputStream());

        //CREA DEGLI OBJECTSTREAM PER L'I/O BASANDOSI SUGLI STREAM OTTENUTI DAL SOCKET
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        oos.flush();

        oos.writeObject(parametri);
        oos.flush();

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        esito = ois.readObject();

        oos.close();
        ois.close();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

    return esito;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object receivedData)
{
    if(receivedData != null)
        receiveData(receivedData);
}}
```

...and this is the Server

public class Server extends Thread {

```
private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
private boolean threadAttivo = true;

public Server(){
    super("threadServerPrincipale");
}

public void startServer(int porta) throws BindException, IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);

    System.out.println("Server in ascolto sulla porta " + porta);

    //AVVIA IL THREAD DI ASCOLTO
    this.start();
}

public void chiudiServer() throws IOException
{
    if(serverSocket != null)
    {
        threadAttivo = false;
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}

public void run()
{
    Socket clientSocket;

    while(threadAttivo)
    {
        try
        {
            //RESTA IN ATTESA DI UNA CONNESSIONE DA PARTE DI UN CLIENT.
            //ALL'ARRIVO DI QUESTA CREA UN SOCKET DI COMUNICAZIONE
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            //PER PERMETTERE LA CONNESSIONE DI PIU' CLIENT CONTEMPORANEAMENTE, IL SOCKET VIENE PASSATO 
            //AD UN'ALTRA CLASSE LA QUALE SI OCCUPERA' DI FORNIRE I SERVIZI RICHIESTI
            new ComunicazioneClient(clientSocket);
        }
        catch(SocketException e){}
        catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

}

public class ComunicazioneClient extends Thread {

```
private InputStream inputStream = null;
private OutputStream outputStream = null;

public ComunicazioneClient(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException
{
    super("thread client" + clientSocket.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());

    inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

    System.out.println("Richiesta del client " + clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());

    start();
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {   
        FrontController frontController = FC.getInstance();

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream));
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));

        Object[] dati = (Object[])ois.readObject();
        Object[] parametri = new Object[dati.length - 1];

        System.arraycopy(dati, 1, parametri, 0, parametri.length);

        String richiesta = (String)dati[0];

        oos.writeObject(frontController.processRequest(richiesta, parametri));
        oos.flush();

        oos.close();
        ois.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (SecurityException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
    catch (InstantiationException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
    catch (NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
}
```

Comment: are you using an ip address or a domain name for connecting? dns resolution may eat some of those 6 seconds

Comment: i'm using an ip address